# How to select a child element when selector is assigned to variable

Tags: jquery

I have assigned a jquery object to a variable. I am using that selector to hide all the elements in it. But I would also like to use that selector and disable all the input fields inside that container.

Is there anyway I can do that by using the variable assigned to the jquery selector ?

For example. to select the all the input fields inside the custom_made_wrapper id I would have to do the following

```
$("#custom_made_wrapper input);
```

But how can I achieve the same thing with the variable I assigned it to .

Below is the code I am using. Any help would be really appreciated!

```
function projBuiltOptions(elem){

var custom_made_wrapper = $("#custom_made_wrapper");
var cms_wrapper = $("#cms_wrapper");

var id = elem.attr("id");

if(id == "custom_made") {

    custom_made_wrapper.prop({disabled:false}).show();
    cms_wrapper.prop({disabled:false}).hide();


} else if(id == "cms" ) {

    cms_wrapper.prop({disabled: false}).show();
    custom_made_wrapper.hide();


   //I would like to achieve something like this..
    custom_made_wrapper.(" input").prop({disabled: true})


}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
//I would like to achieve something like this..
custom_made_wrapper.find("input").prop({disabled: true});

// or this for immediated children
custom_made_wrapper.children("input").prop({disabled: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.find()`

```
custom_made_wrapper.find(" input").prop({disabled: true})
```

Comment: @json2021 good luck man .. please sign the Nikos M answer as a accepted answer ..